# Creating a Django web-app with Sage 200 Database

Tags: python, database-design, django, report-generation

I have been asked to create a Django/Python web app that creates web-based, .pdf and excel reports from a Sage Evolution database. While the sage front-end is still being used. My client essentially wants to create their own "Sage" by only adding the features they need in a web app and hence making the process easier to understand for some of their workers.

I have started with some things such as printing Trial Balances and Income Statements and all is going well. However there are some things in this challenge that are really difficult to tackle, for example - the Age Analysis structure represented on Sage's system is nothing close to what the exact database structure looks like.

I was wondering if anyone else had done this previously, however, I cant seem to find any online resources that can aid in this process.

If anyone has done this before and has the resources they used to make this happen, please kindly share below - it would help me out endlessly?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any of this, check the **Licence Agreement** that governs your [permitted] usage of Sage!

You may be *contractually barred* from doing exactly what you're trying to do.

At best, you may find that some upgrade to Sage itself breaks *your* stuff.
At worst, you may one day find yourself with a broken Sage system and, because you've been "hacking about" with it, its vendors *refusing* to support you (or *charging* you a *lot* more for the privilege!)

For example, if you're directly querying the underlying database, then you're engaging in "Reverse Engineering" of said database (to work out what's in it).   That's one of the [many] things that are commonly *prohibited* in software Licences.